# Sorting a IP addr using regex by its first octect

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, sorting

I am trying to read all the IP address from a log file. I create a list of unique IP addresses and want to display the sorted list in terms of an IP address

```
import sys
import re

def ip_check(temp):
  str=re.search(r"(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)",temp)
  return str.group(1)

def main():
  file=open(sys.argv[1],'rU')
  text=file.read()
  file.close()
  string = re.findall(r"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+",text)
  ip_addr = list(set(string))
  for item in sorted(ip_addr, key=ip_check, reverse=False):
    print item,'\n'

if _ terms _name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Problem is I am getting the list sorted in terms of the first characters in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String comparisons are by ["Lexicographical order"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), that's why you got the impression it sorts by the first number. That's because it sorts element-wise, first it compares the first character, if they are equal then the second, if they are equal then the third, and so on.

You need to convert it to a number to get number-like comparisons:

```
def ip_check(temp):
    str=re.search(r"(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)",temp)
    return int(str.group(1))  # convert to integer
```

For example:

```
def main():
    # I don't have your log file so I just made one up myself...
    text = """128.128.123.1
3.1.1.1
0.0.0.1"""
    string = re.findall(r"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+",text)
    ip_addr = list(set(string))
    for item in sorted(ip_addr, key=ip_check, reverse=False):
        print (item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

gives:

```
0.0.0.1
3.1.1.1
128.128.123.1
```